# How to determine if the user is using a cellular connection programmatically in a Mac App

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I wanted to know if there is any way for me to determine if the system is accessing the internet over an attached modem, typically with a limited-data connection.

In other words, what is OS X's equivalent of `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN`?

Comment: Its a portable USB device used to connect to the internet on-the-go, a 3G/4G dongle. Kinda like the chromecast thing but for accessing internet.